# Which DataGridView event do I use when I want to change the type of a cell at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a winform application that has a user control that is using a DataGridView control on it.

When rendering the DataGridView I want some of the rows Quantity columns cells to be read only DataGridViewTextBox cells and other rows  to a a DataGridViewComboBoxCell.

What is the appropriate DataGridView event to use this.  CellFormatting or CellPaint or some other event?

Comment: you cant do that.  DGV Columns are components which get added to the DGV in the designer and remain the Type they were when created. You can create a new cell (eg a ComboCell) at runtime though and place it in the DGV to change from Text to a CBO.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23717051/1070452

Comment: What's the condition, with out conditions and what you really want to achieve is a long shot. I can say this can be easily done with a method.